# Calendar details on click

Tags: 2010, calendar

I have a web part page created with a left body and side column layout.  I created 2 views of a calendar to put on this page that will allow a monthly calendar view to display in the left body and a small daily calendar to the right in the right column.

How can I show details for the day when someone clicks a day on the left monthly view it will show the details on the right column daily view?

I guess this would be master/detail webpage but since you can't have connected web parts with calendar view I am at a loss. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a third-party Js library like full-Calendar or some other jQuery calendars as they provide almost all of the functionings.

see the [link](http://www.queness.com/post/656/10-beautiful-jquery-and-mootool-calendar-plugins)

you can also check [this link](https://mhusseini.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/handle-clicks-on-calendar-items-in-sharepoint-2010-with-javascript/)

it describes to override the default API function " **SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarContainerFactory.create** " of the SharePoint calendar view and apply a custom hook of your own as posted below.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
    MyCalendarHook, 
    "SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js");

function MyCalendarHook() {     
    var _patchCalendar = function() {        
        $('.ms-acal-rootdiv .ms-acal-item').click(function () {
            var itemId = $('a', $(this)).attr('href').split('?ID=')[1];
            alert('Item with ID ' + itemId + ' was clicked!');
        });
    };

    var _onItemsSucceed = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed;
    SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed = function($p0, $p1) {
        _onItemsSucceed.call(this, $p0, $p1);
        _patchCalendar();
    };
}
```

and add this script file in your v4.master head tag as show below. (Script included between **BEGIN DEMO** and **END DEMO** )

```
<head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
  <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint"/>
  <meta name="progid" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
  <SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"/>
  <title id="onetidTitle"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/></title>
  <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="4"/>
  <SharePoint:Theme runat="server"/>
  <SharePoint:ULSClientConfig runat="server"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var _fV4UI = true;
  </script>
  <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server"/>
  <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server"/>
  <SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server"/>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server"/>
  <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
  <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/images/favicon.ico"/>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server"/>
  <!-- BEGIN DEMO -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/js/patchcalendar.js"></script>
  <!-- END DEMO -->
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server"/>
  <SharePoint:SPPageManager runat="server"/>
  <SharePoint:SPHelpPageComponent Visible="false" runat="server"/>
</head>
```